# Plotly graph exported as html is not shown at all on mobile phone

Tags: python, html, mobile, plotly

I've been creating different graphs using python plotly and then exporting them as html.
They worked perfectly on computers but they completely dissapear and nothing is shown in mobile phone devices.
Any idea on why this could be?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add some code example and some details about your system and your implementation? This helps to reproduce the error and provide useful answers :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.